# jquery dynamic form and dynamic population

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to put to work this simple script that stores phone numbers in a .txt file. The problem is I can't populate correctly with the jquery-dynamic-form. Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks a lot in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-dynamic-form.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#phone2Template").dynamicForm("#plus6", "#minus6", {limit:5, createColor:"red"});
            });
        </script>
</head><body><pre>
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){ // var_dump($_POST);
$f = @fopen ("phones.txt","w");
foreach ($_POST['phone2Template']['phone2Template'] as $key) {
         $lines .= $key['phone2']."\n"; }
fwrite($f, "$lines");fclose($f);} else {
$f = @fopen ("phones.txt","r"); $result = fread($f,filesize("phones.txt")); fclose($f);
$alllines = split("\n",$result);
echo '</pre><form method="post" action="#" value="Post">    
<fieldset><p id=\'phone2Template\'>'; 
 for($i=0;$i<count($alllines);$i++) { 
  echo '<label for="phone2">telephone: </label><input id="phone2" type="text" name="phone2" value='.$alllines[$i].'><br />'; }
echo '<span style="clear:none; float:right;"><a id="minus6" href="">[-]</a> <a id="plus6" href="">[+]</a></span></p></fieldset><input type="submit" /></form></body></html>';    
}
?>
```

Comment: I've found a way, using mainDynamicForm.inject(data) as shown here: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-dynamic-form/source/browse/trunk/index.php
Thanks anyway!